# Search in a column sql by first and last characters

Tags: php, psql, postgresql-9.4

In my data table I have a column `reference`, data of this column is composed of **categorie** + **idproduct** + **idmaker** example:

```
reference      | categorie + idproduct + idmaker
---------------|--------------------
cat48934547814 | [cat48][934][547814]
cat55548451412 | [cat55][548][451412] 
cat48548547814 | [cat48][548][547814]
```

I want search all product having the reference that starts with `cat48` and ends by `547814`.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a pair of like

```
select  * 
from my_table  
where reference like 'cat48%' 
and reference like '%547814'
```

or with substring

```
select  * 
from my_table  
where left(reference, 5)  = 'cat48' 
and right(reference ,6) = '547814'
```

Comment: Thanks, i thought i was getting better with substring :)

Comment: Thank's, because for performance's reasons, it is less recommended to use the "like" ;)